# How to load the db2 table from ps dataset using jcl utility DSNUTLIB?

Tags: db2, mainframe, jcl

I am using the JCL utility `DSNUTLIB`

And the JCL is,

```
//STEP01    EXEC PGM=DSNUTILB,
//          REGION=0M
//SYSPRINT  DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSUDUMP  DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSOUT    DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSREC01  DD DSN=INPUTFILE.TEST,DISP=SHR
//SYSIN DD *
 LOAD DATA
 INDDN SYSREC01
 REPLACE
 INTO TABLE "table_schema.table_name"
 ( COL_1 POSITION(1) CHAR (8)
  , COL_2 POSITION(9) CHAR (8)
  , COL_3 POSITION(17) CHAR(200)
  )
/*
```

When i am submiting the JCL i am geting SOC4E ana the error code = E40002.

Comment: Although we pronounce it "sock", that is a zero not an "O". S0C4E. However, it is not a S0C4E, which is too long, but an S04E. When you search with that and the E number (which you chopped as well) what do you discover?:

Comment: The error msg in spool is DSNUTILB - UTILITY BATCH MEMORY EXECUTION ABENDED, REASON=X'00E40002'

Comment: Can you post the JOBLIB DD from the JOB, all of it, including any concatenations.